# Spawning a robot arm with desired joint angles

Tags: gazebo, joint, collision, state, kinova

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to spawn a Kinova Mico arm in a gazebo simulation and Rviz. It spawns with all the joints at a value of 0.
This means that they spawn in collision state, shown below. Both in rviz and they spawn in the same state.
[image: image description]

I am trying to execute movement from the real hardware arm, so rotating the joints in the URDF model is not a solution to solving this problem. How can I spawn the robot with rotated joints?

EDIT:

Added the suggested answer but didn't fix anything.

```
  <node name="urdf_spawner" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model"
    args="-urdf 
    -model mico 
    -param robot_description 
    -J mico_joint_1 0
    -J mico_joint_2 1.5708
    -J mico_joint_3 1.5708
    -J mico_joint_4 0
    -J mico_joint 5 0
    -J mico_joint_6 0
    -z 1.0" 
    respawn="false" output="screen"/>
```

I also get this message:

```
[INFO] [WallTime: 1465542497.231790] [0.000000] temporary hack to **fix** the -J joint position option (issue #93), sleeping for 1 second to avoid race condition.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236568/spawning-a-robot-arm-with-desired-joint-angles/) by [Laurens Verhulst](https://answers.ros.org/users/26924/laurens-verhulst/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2016-06-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok found the answer here on [github](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/issues/93).
It was indeed -J joint_name joint_angle. However, you have to wait til all the controllers are initiated and then execute the spawn command. It's a work-around apparently.

---

Originally posted by [Laurens Verhulst](https://answers.ros.org/users/26924/laurens-verhulst/) with karma: 167 on 2016-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1